# CSS: line-break ignores padding?

Tags: css

I have no idea why this is happening …

```
<div class="inner">
    <em class="wrapper tiny">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et </em>
</div>
```

`.inner` has a simple left and right margin applied. 
the `em.wrapper` tag has a padding applied.

I have no idea why the second line the is automatically broken by the browser width is ignoring the padding of the `.wrapper` box?

Any ideas on that?

[image]

Comment: Hey OP, consider accepting Michael's answer.

Answer (score 49):

The `em` tag is `display: inline` by default. Try adding `display: inline-block` to the class definition.

```css
.wrapper {
  /* ... */
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: This helped me a lot - thank you. Works fine.

@matt Mark this one as answer.

Comment: This is the actuall answer to this problem. I had the problem too, today. I used a span, which is an inline element, so I changed it to a block element ( `display: block;` or `display: inline-block` should do it too) and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Your padding is set to 0

```
padding: 0 0.75em
```

means padding top and padding bottom are 0px and that padding left and padding right are 0.75em.

update that line of CSS to:

```
padding : 0.75em
```

Comment: actually, I took another look at the question and this isn't it.